# "Everybody thought we should sell" vs "Everybody thought we should have sold"

Tags: modal-verbs, backshifting

> 1. Everybody thought we should sell
> 2. Everybody thought we should have sold

While I was watching the news, I came to wonder about this question.

As far as I know, the tense after "that" should be also the past tense. 
(e.g. *He told me that I **looked** sick*)

As I figured, in the sentence "Everybody told me that we should sell" the moment everybody told him they should sell was in the past. But why still it's should?

I don't know how to deal with modal verbs when the tense should be in the past form.

Comment: I mean, I'm aware that "should" is the past form of "shall" but we use "should" for every situation. So, I figured maybe there should be some kind of distinction to be made...?  ( I realized I'm using "should" in the past tense situation myself)

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two involves the relative order in time between their thinking and your selling. Both sentences say that at some point in the past, everyone did some thinking. But according to the first sentence, their opinion was that it would be well if you were to sell at some time **after** that. By contrast, the second sentence says that it would have been well if you had **already** by then sold.